# Ошибка с OpenIabHelper

Tags: c#, unity3d

в консоли разработчика стал получать `ANR` ошибку:

```
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
Unity version     : 5.6.4p4
Device model      : samsung SAMSUNG-SM-T377A
Device fingerprint: samsung/gteslteuc/gteslteatt:7.1.1/NMF26X/T377AUCS3BRE1:user/release-keys
Caused by
  at org.onepf.oms.OpenIabHelper.checkSetupDone (OpenIabHelper.java:1517)
  at org.onepf.oms.OpenIabHelper.queryInventoryAsync (OpenIabHelper.java:1413)
  at org.onepf.openiab.UnityPlugin$4.run (UnityPlugin.java:165)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6823)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1557)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

на множество девайсов, обновил версию `OpenIAP`, ошибка осталась, эта же система находится и в другом проекте, и в нем этих ошибок нет, хотя я там тоже обновил этот плагин, не могу понять в чем дело. Все необходимые строки добавил в манифест.

Манифест
https://pastebin.com/VKbKkvFJ

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что создаваемый объект `"PurchaseManager"` при запуске игры уже находился на сцене.